# Accessing Java Applet non-static methods using Java

Tags: java, javascript, applet, non-static, japplet

I'm trying to access non-static methods in a java applet, through javascript.

I access static methods using the Syntax `AppletName.Packages.className.methodName();` and it works.

If I try to access a non-static member/method via JavaScript, I get an error "`Error calling method on NPObject`", but nothing on the Java Console.

Is there a way to access non-static applet methods from Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a java object, then you can call your methods.

```
var myClass = new AppletName.Packages.className();
myClass.methodName();
```

From [here](http://www.webreference.com/javascript/reference/core_ref/javobj.html).

Answer (score 0):

See [Call a Java method from Javascript](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html).